# Different image rendering in Safari, Chrome and Firefox

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, safari, jpeg

I was doing browser compatibility checks for client and noticed something strange. Image was rendered differently on browsers. For example chrome added color to the image, Safari and Firefox had different hues of grey (this is kinda ok, but chrome adding color to the image I can't explain).

Here is the SS of image loaded in the browsers :

[image: Chrome, Safari, Firefox rendering bear.jpg]

And here is the original image : 
[Original Bear.jpg](https://ibb.co/fWgHyd)

Also when I downloaded image, It was grey in MacOS and Windows. Can anybody explain what is happening and why ? O.o

Comment: Any explanation since then?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but its still rendering it in diff ways :) 4 years later